# Код в Python не работает

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, цифра увеличилась на 1 единицу ?

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *

setup(800, 700)
bgcolor("cyan")

def score():
    dollar = 0
    dollar +=1
    label_scorre = Label(text=dollar, bg="cyan", font=("Arial 70"))
    label_scorre.place(x=370, y=200)

button_click = Button(text="Click", width=7, height=1, bg="orange", fg="red", activebackground="orange", activeforeground="red", bd=6, font=("Arial 35"), command=score)
button_click.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)

done()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать, скажем, через глобальную переменную:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import *

setup(800, 700)
bgcolor("cyan")
score = 0

def add_score():
    global score

    score += 1
    label_scorre = Label(text=score, bg="cyan", font=("Arial 70"))
    label_scorre.place(x=370, y=200)

button_click = Button(text="Click", width=7, height=1, bg="orange", fg="red", activebackground="orange", activeforeground="red", bd=6, font=("Arial 35"), command=add_score)
button_click.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)

done()
```

Но глобали - не лучшая практика, да и ООП - важная часть python, так что я бы все обернул в класс:

```
from tkinter import (
    Label,
    Button,
    CENTER,
)
from turtle import (
    setup,
    bgcolor,
    done,
)


class Window:


    def __init__(self):
        
        setup(800, 700)
        bgcolor("cyan")

        self.score = 0

        self.label = Label(text=self.score, bg="cyan", font=("Arial 70"))
        self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        
        self.main_button = Button(
            text="Click", 
            width=7, 
            height=1, 
            bg="orange", 
            fg="red", 
            activebackground="orange", 
            activeforeground="red", bd=6, 
            font=("Arial 35"), 
            command=self.add_score
        )
        self.main_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)


    def add_score(self):

        self.score += 1
        self.label.config(text=self.score)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":

    window = Window()
    done()
```